# Can't render shortcode when html tag contains hyphen

Tags: shortcode

Let's say I have a web component called `<x-interaction>`. I want to pass the ID of the post to the web component as an attribute, so I write a shortcode to render the ID.

```php
add_shortcode('get_the_id', 'get_the_ID');
```

In the post I write the following:

```html
<x-interaction postid=[get_the_id]>
  <span slot="title">This is slotted content</span>
</x-interaction>
```

So far, so good.

But the shortcode isn't rendered on the page. **The shortcode appears verbatim in the rendered HTML.**

I want this:

```html
<x-interaction postid="4">
```

But I get this:

```html
<x-interaction postid="[get_the_id]">
```

What? ‍

As an experiment, I removed the hyphen from the tag name, and the shortcode renders appropriately: `<xinteraction>`

```html
<xinteraction postid="4">
```

**This seems to be related to the hyphen in the web component tag name.** Or something else with Wordpress and web components that I don't know.

Comment: Shortcodes are [explicitly not intended to be used in HTML attributes](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/08/30/shortcodes-roadmap/). This is a mis-use of shortcodes. Besides, shortcodes are an antiquated feature of WordPress. The proper way to implement this would be with [a custom block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/).

Comment: If you _insist_ on using shortcodes then the proper solution would be to make this whole block of HTML a shortcode, not just the id. Something like `[x_interaction id="4" title="This is slotted content"]` which output the markup you wanted.